# Object oriented PHP and third party plugin in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I need to use a third party php plugin in one of my classes. So I was wondering where should I include the third party php file ? `require_once 'plugin.php';`

The plugin functions will be used in different functions of the class. Is constructor of the class a good place to do that ? Or maybe just outside the class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the external plugin in the **third_party** folder and reference it by using the `APPPATH` constant like this

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear :( The plugin is not a codeigniter plugin, it doesn't follow the codeigniter naming convention and other requirements.

Comment: it does not need to .. which plugin are you using ?

Comment: The plugin is HTMLPurifier htmlpurifier.org

Comment: What is the usage ??  Do you doe something like  `$pluginObject  = new myNewPluginClass()` ??

Comment: Like this : $this->purifier = new HTMLPurifier(  HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault (  )  );

Comment: well in that case i would suggest  you place the HTML Purifier directory in the `third_party` folder and refrence it. Will just update my answer

Comment: Yes, but the question is where to include the file ?

Comment: you can include the file in the controller file wherever it is being used